# how to set font feature file for a specific font file and not the whole font shape

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, libertine

I'm looking for having my document set with specific ligatures, such as 's' replaced by 'longs', 's t' by 'longs_t' etc. and using the Linux Libertine G font.

To do this, I'm writing my text normally with 's' and I'm using a font feature file together with the fontspec package and compiling with Lualatex.

This works properly. Here if the font feature file:

```
#font.fea
languagesystem DFLT dflt ;
languagesystem latn dflt ;

feature oplt {
    @notf = [a b c d e g j k m n o p q r u v w x y z];
    sub s' @notf by longs;
    sub longs longs' by s; # words don't end with longs
    sub f longs' by s;     # end with fs, not f_longs
} oplt;

feature oooo {
    sub s s by longs_s;
    sub s s by germandbls.alt;
    sub s t by longs_t;
    sub s h by longs_h;
    sub s i by longs_i;
    sub s l by longs_l;
    sub s s i by longs_longs_i;
} oooo;
```

here is a piece of code compiled with Lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=font.fea, RawFeature=+oplt,RawFeature=+oooo]{Linux Libertine G Regular}
\begin{document}
  ssi
  \textit{ssi}
\end{document}
```

The issue I have is, this will fail. Lualatex ends with

```
 !LuaTeX error (file C:/Windows/Fonts/linlibertineg_it.ttf): Invalid glyph index
  (gid 2335)
```

My understanding is that the font feature file is applied to the whole font shapes (italic, bold, etc.), but the thing is some of the glyphs I put in the feature file are present in the regular file and not in the italic/bold shapes.

That is the case for the longs_longs_i ligature, which is defined in the regular shape of Linux Libertine Graphite and not in the Italic shape. I didn't clearly find the way to use fontspec to set-up my feature file only for the regular shape and not for the other shapes.

Is there any workaround, apart from embedding the features in the font file ?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t have Linux Libertine Graphite, but the approach I’ve used with Linux Libertine O will probably work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec}
\begin{filecontents*}{font.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt ;
languagesystem latn dflt ;

feature oplt {
    @notf = [a b c d e g j k m n o p q r u v w x y z];
    sub s' @notf by longs;
    sub longs longs' by s; # words don't end with longs
    sub f longs' by s;     # end with fs, not f_longs
} oplt;

feature oooo {
    sub s s by longs_s;
    sub s s by germandbls.alt;
    sub s t by longs_t;
    sub s h by longs_h;
    sub s i by longs_i;
    sub s l by longs_l;
} oooo;

feature zzzz {
    sub s s i by longs_longs_i;
} zzzz;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=font.fea,RawFeature=+oplt,RawFeature=+oooo,UprightFeatures={RawFeature=+zzzz}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
  ssi
  \textit{ssi}
\end{document}
```

See section 7.4 of the fontspec manual for explanations.