# Accessing user-selectable features in GentiumPlus in XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, opentype

Specifically, the combination of **f** plus **î** in the italic ends up with the upper curl of the **f** smashed into the peak of the circumflex (other fonts have the same problem, but the result is even uglier). I would like to improve the situation by using the GentiumPlus user-selectable feature "Low-profile diacritics" (feature ID code `lopr` in the latest release (version 1.510), `1054` in previous releases --per the newest version of *gentiumPlus-features.pdf*, apparently only available online in the font package [download](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/render_download.php?format=file&media_id=GentiumPlus-1.510.zip&filename=GentiumPlus-1.510.zip)-- with values `1=true` and `0=false`, as corrected in the [SIL tech notes](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Gentium_Technical#bef1c519) for this font).

This would produce a squatter circumflex that *should* miss the collision with **f**.

Other notes on the SIL page regarding features new with GentiumPlus *seems* to indicate that this feature is available both as Graphite and OpenType features, and since I would like to be able to do this in both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, I would like to use OpenType, since Graphite is not supported in LaTeX (except possibly via the Fontspec back door of including Graphite instructions in a Font Feature File, as mentioned in a post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119051/how-to-set-font-feature-file-for-a-specific-font-file-and-not-the-whole-font-sha), but not in the Fontspec manual, where it is supposed that it will only be used for OpenType features).

Now *if* I am reading the Fontspec documentation correctly, and *if* I am correct that this exists as an OpenType feature, I can add this feature with `\addICUfeature` (in XeLaTeX) or `\addopentypefeature` (in LuaLaTeX). The [Fonspec manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) (page 43) gives the syntax (using the XeLaTeX version of the command name) as

> `\newICUfeature{<feature>}{<option>}{<feature tag>}`

with an example (using the LuaLaTeX version)

> `\newopentypefeature{Style}{NoLocalForms}{-locl}`

Comparing with the syntax and use of `\addAATfeature` on the same page, it seems clear that `<feature>` and `<option>` are the names that would go on the righthand and lefthand sides of the `=` in an argument to e.g. `\addfontfeatures`, while `<feature tag>` would, in this case, be `+lopr`, assuming a prefixed plus/minus sign works as an on or off switch.

**BUT** I seem not to have done this correctly. I had guessed that `<feature>` and `<option>` were simply user-created discriptive names, as with `\newcommand`. What I used was

> `\newICUfeature{GentiumPlusFeatures}{LowProfile}{+lopr}`

in the preamble, and for an activation command (which I grouped with just the combining circumflex character, immediately following the dotless i) I used

> `fı{\addfontfeature{GentiumPlusFeatures=LowProfile}\char"0302}`

My document compiled successfully without stopping, but the result was visually identical to the combined characters *without* the command, and with the original i-circumflex character. The log shows a fontspec warning `"icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"` with an explanation

```
OpenType feature 'GentiumPlusFeatures=LowProfile' (+lopr) not available for  
font 'GentiumPlus-R.ttf' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
```

Finally, I tried adding `Renderer=ICU` to the `\addfontfeatures` argument, as suggested in a possibly-relevant post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126340/small-caps-in-gentium-plus-after-miktex-update) but the result was unchanged. (I am guessing `Renderer=ICU` would still be necessary once corrections to the rest are made, but also don't know that `Renderer=ICU` would work in LuaLaTeX).

UPDATE: I have tried substituting the name `Low-profile diacritics` in the `<feature>` field and `True` for `<option>`, so that by using these, along with `+lopr` (plus trial variants `-lopr` and `lopr`), I am now using only the exact language of the font documentation, but still no success.

I have gone as far as I can with this on my own, and am hoping someone with real expertise will be able to look it over and fix it in a few seconds. It is a small thing, I know... much like a grape seed in one's appendix.

Comment: As it appears this is a "can't get there from here" scenario for LuaLaTeX, I have changed tactics and modified the font, which was easily done with SIL's online version of their TypeTuner tool. Just a few clicks and I had a new version of the font with the low-profile diacritics set as default, usable as such in any application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, there is a misconception here, LaTeX as a macro package neither supports OpenType nor Graphite nor it is its duty, those are to be supported by the underlying engine. The LaTeX package for using modern fonts and features, `fontspec`, do support Graphite but it is a rather rudimentary support. Font feature files is a LuaTeX-specific feature and are OpenType-only, they has nothing to do with LaTeX or Graphite.

The features you want are Graphite features, so they won’t work with LuaTeX.

You cannot use `\newICUfeature` either, as it will force check for OpenType features, and since `fontspec` does not provide a `\newgraphitefeature` command, you can use the generic `\newfontfeature` that accepts arbitrary input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfeature{LowDiacritics}{Low-profile diacritics=True}
\newfontfeature{HighDiacritics}{Low-profile diacritics=False}
\begin{document}
\fontspec[Renderer=Graphite,LowDiacritics]{Gentium Plus}
èáä fî
\fontspec[Renderer=Graphite,HighDiacritics]{Gentium Plus}
èáä fî
\end{document}
```

[image: Result sample]

Here I used the descriptive feature names, since all versions of XeTeX support them. Recent versions can use the numeric ID or the 4-letter tags.